# Creating different types of circles like GooglePlus

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Happy New year to all,
i am creating a social network for doctors using express,angular,node and MongoDb, fairly new to these technologies, i have been thinking to create different type **circles** for a particular user just like **googleplus** where we have different circles like **friends** and **family**, here i want to create circles of doctors with different specialities, and wondering how i should handle it on backend

**Schema:**

```
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({

UserID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'

NetworkList: [ ],
});
```

so far what i have been thinking is to insert different objects having field name of different **specialities** like- heartSpecialist, Cardiologists etc. inside **NetworkList** array, it should be generic so, i left NetworkList array - **empty**, may be i not much correct with this logic, here is document

```
{
"NetworkList" : [ 
    HeartSpecialist: [ //ObjectId's of HeartSpecialist ],
    CardioLogists: [//ObjectId's of CardioLogists ]
   ..
],
"UserID" : ObjectId("54aa46ef65c266341494a528"),

"_id" : ObjectId("54aa46ef65c266341494a529")
}
```

when i used discriminator for schema type like:

```
var portalSchema = new Schema(),
CircleType = new Schema({
    ID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }

});
CIRCLE = Portal.discriminator('CIRCLE', CircleType);
function logger(label,content) {
    console.log(
        '%s:\n%s\n', label,
        util.inspect( content, false, 8, false ) );

}
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        var circleObj = new CIRCLE({'ID': req.body.Fid});
        circleObj.save(function(err,circleObj) {
            logger('Circles', circleObj);
            callback(err,circleObj);
        });

    },
    function(circleObj,callback){
        var get = {'UserID':req.body.UserID};
        var up = {$push:{'NetworkList':circleObj}};
Network.update(get,up,{upsert:true},function(err,user){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return err;}});
]);
```

**Resulted Document:**

```
{

"NetworkList" : [ 
    {
        "__v" : 0,
        "ID" : ObjectId("54a6de049754e5940c97435a"),
        "__t" : "CIRCLE",
        "_id" : ObjectId("54aa48ccba36d7ac1810e832")
    }, 

],

"UserID" : ObjectId("54aa46ef65c266341494a528"),
"_id" : ObjectId("54aa46ef65c266341494a529")
}
```

I know this logic is whole different of what i described above or what i want, so far i have came with this where i can differentiate with type doctor having **'__t'** in above document, may be i am not looking for code but a logic to achieve circle type functionality.
Thank you

**EDIT:**
problem:-when a doctor of same circle type is added, a new object of same circle type is being stored in database which leads to redundancy

```
{
"NetworkList" : [ 
    {
        "__v" : 0,
        "ID" : ObjectId("54aa46ef65c266341494a528"),
        "__t" : "CIRCLE",                            //two different objects of same circle
        "_id" : ObjectId("54aa4a40bf50c41c14e389c4")
    }, 
    "54aa46ef65c266341494a528", 
    {
        "__v" : 0,
        "ID" : ObjectId("54a6de049754e5940c97435a"),
        "__t" : "CIRCLE",
        "_id" : ObjectId("54aa4add024eebd81fe009a2")
    }, 

],

"UserID" : ObjectId("54a8291f8ed9a2b41eb164ff"),
"__v" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("54a8291f8ed9a2b41eb16500")
}
```

Comment: Hmm, some of this looks like code I listed for an answer but it was not given to you. Same team perhaps. If you truly play around with "discriminators" then you would find that when your query by that "model type" then values of `__t` are "auto-magically" filtered for that "Object type". Much like the original person asking, your approach seems a little off where you want to be in a final objective though.

Comment: we are on same team, as if now i am working on user-circles module, yeah my approach may be little off because here whenever i update Network model, a new circleObj is inserted every time, so may be my whole logic is wrong, how should i achieve it then

Comment: It seems so, but what I'm trying to aid with is that is exactly what is making this unclear. Simple terms. Everything in your "NetworkList" array should "inherit" from a base object into new types defined by "discriminators". This is how mongoose will do the polymorphic mapping to types. If one type is a `Doctor` then you can query for just those items on the "base collection" by querying from that model and "Doctor" in the `__v` will be automatically filtered for you. It's hard to explain  because it looks like you have things in the wrong place. The orig answer explains in some detail.

Comment: Yeah, i got your point but here on every update on Network Model circleObj  of same type is saving to database, the problem is what if i add another user/doctor of same circle type, so there will be another object inserted into database of circle type type. I am confused what query i should use so that i would be able to store the objectId of doctor of same circle type in a single Object .I am editing question to make things more clear